# Learning the DOM

Tags: javascript, dom

I'm learning the DOM in JavaScript and I was doing ok but for some reason, my code isn't working and I have no idea why. I wanted to test running a for loop to change the class of all the elements in an unordered list and it worked, kind of. It skips over one for some reason but everything I do confirms that the index and everything are correct. It gets the one before it and the one after but not it for some reason.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <title>repl.it</title>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="page">
      <h1 id="header">List</h1>
      <h2>Buy Groceries</h2>
      <ul>
        <li id="one" class="hot"><em>fresh</em> figs</li>
        <li id="two" class="hot">pine nuts</li>
        <li id="three" class="hot">honey</li>
        <li id="four" class="hot">balsamic vinegar</li>
      </ul>
      <script src="script.js"></script>
    </div>

  </body>
</html>
```

```css
.hot {
  color: red;
}

.cold {
  color: blue;
}
```

```js
let hot = document.getElementsByClassName("hot");

for (let i = 0; i <= hot.length; i++) {
  hot[i].className = "cold";
};
```

When I run this, every other item in the list turns blue (fresh figs and honey) but the others (pine nuts and balsamic vinegar) don't. I just can't figure out why it's skipping.

Any help would be greatly appreciated thank you.

Comment: I recommend against `getElementsByClassName`, it returns a live collection, which is very unintuitive. Use `querySelectorAll`, which is not live (and is also more flexible, and also has a `forEach` method built-in)

Comment: Also `i <= hot.length;` you have an off-by-one error